# eyed3 "can't concat bytes to str"

Tags: linux, python-3.x

```
from eyed3 import id3
tag=id3.Tag()
tag.parse("song.mp3")
tag.artist=u"Bilan"
print(tag.artist)
tag.save()
```

Всё работает, выдает тэг, который я присвоил, но не получается сохранить, пишет ошибку - "can't concat bytes to str"

Сижу на линуксе, использую python3.
Также проблема в том, что есть например Аудиофайл с тэгами, но он не хочет их читать, просто пишет, что тэг = None.

Comment: Префикс `u` перед строкой не имеет смысла. "For backwards compatibility with the Python 2 series, the u prefix is once again permitted on string literals. It has no effect on the meaning of string literals"

Comment: Потому что Python 3.x. Сидели бы себе спокойно на 2.7.x.